# (Google Drive) File has parent but can't get to file from parent

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

A file does not appear in its folder, either visually (at drive.google.com) or programmatically (via folder.getFiles()). The file also does not appear when searched for in Google Drive.

The only "weird" thing about this is that the owner of the file and the folder are different.

I own the folder and a coworker owns the file. We can both see the folder and we can both access the file via direct link, but neither of us can see the file in the folder. The coworker has edit access to the file; I inherit access to the file when they add it to the folder I own.

In the below code, Logger.log should log the name of the file, but doesn't:

```
function test06182019() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var folders = file.getParents();
  var folder = folders.next(); //the file has only one parent. Yes, I've checked.
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()){
    Logger.log(files.next().getName()); //should list the name of "file" above
  }
}
```

To reproduce:

```
folderIDontOwn.addFile(fileIOwn);
DriveApp.removeFile(fileIOwn); //removes from root, not from a specific or every folder
```

...where folderIDontOwn is a folder you don't own but have edit access to and fileIOwn is a file you own.

I expect to see the file in the folder, both visually (at drive.google.com) and programmatically (via folder.getFiles()).

Comment: What is your use case where this is a problem? Or is it just "hey isn't this weird". You might be able to force something with set parents or with copying the file to the folder programmatically.

Comment: In my environment, I could confirm that the filename could be retrieved by the following flow. 1. Prepare UserA and UserB who have Google Drive. 2. UserA has a folder and the folder is shared with UserB. 3. UserB has a file (Spreadsheet as a sample). 4. UserB put the file to the shared folder using the script. 5. When UserA run the script of ``test06182019()``, ``Logger.log(files.next().getName())`` shows the filename.

Comment: If above flow was not correct for replicating your situation, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the flow for completely replicating your situation? I would like to replicate your situation and think of about the issue.

Comment: I have found that when removing files from drive, the API is still able to find them through methods like `list()` while they are in trash, even if they don't visually show in the drive. Also, have you tried looking for the file through its name or ID? I see in your example you are calling `getFiles()`, it might be getting something else

Comment: J.G. I process paperwork; my coworkers often have stacks (50+ files) that are my responsibility. They use Scripts to put them in my folders so I can process them.
Tanaike that is correct; unfortunately, it doesn't happen all the time. I am unable to pin it down beyond the code I provided but I am keeping an eye out for more information. I will say that we are adding 50+ files at a time.
AlbertoMolina it's possible the file can be found by listing all files; however, I know which folder it should be in, so for efficiency, I only want to look in that folder (I have 1000+ files in Drive).

Comment: I was able to replicate the same scenario Tanaike described, and the file is shown both in the code and visually, I also tried having a third user be the file's creator, then share it with userB, to check if it was something with the permissions, and then have userB add it to the shared folder with userA, both A and B were able to see the file without issue. 

I believe that your issue might relate to a bug with drive or a propagation delay (the latter being more likely). I couldn't replicate the behavior you're seeing, and I believe it has to do with the amount of files you have.

Comment: @AlbertoMolina, okay, so perhaps just adding a 0.5s delay between each file? I ~really~ appreciate the extent both of you went to to try and reproduce the issue!!!

Comment: I don't think adding the delay would solve this issue, since we cannot reproduce this from our end, and since any further investigating would require PII, I think your next step should be to contact GSuite support directly (if you have a license), they can better address this matter since they can analyze the affected files/folders. In the meantime, I'd suggest you to split the files between different folders, to reduce the amount on a single one.
You can create the case [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: @AlbertoMolina, yes, we are already splitting the files depending on whose paperwork they are. For instance, my coworker might upload an I9 for one person and a W4 for another. They go in separate folders per person. I will create a case -- thanks!